# Maui Maps Binding MarkerClicked Event

Tags: binding, maps, maui, pins

Im trying to bind a command to the marker clicked event on Maui maps. I have binded pins using a DataTemplate. I can get it to work via the MainPage.xaml.cs but my app is using a viewModel. I can not bind the event.

```
<maps:Map x:Name="map" IsShowingUser="true" ItemsSource="{Binding SavedSpots}" >               
    <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <maps:Pin Location="{Binding Location}"
                  Address="{Binding Address}"
                  Label="{Binding Label}"
                  MarkerClicked="{Binding Pin_MarkerClicked}">                        
            </maps:Pin>
        </DataTemplate>
    </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
</maps:Map>
```

I have tried the CommunityToolkit EventToCommandBehavior but the map does not have any behaviors.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

I have tried all the code that every has suggested. I dont think it can be done that way as it is a field under the Pin.

```
    namespace Microsoft.Maui.Maps
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a Pin that displays a map.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IMapPin : IElement
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The physical address that is associated with this pin.
        /// </summary>
        string Address { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The label that is shown for this pin.
        /// </summary>
        string Label { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The geographical location of this pin.
        /// </summary>
    Location Location { get; }

    object? MarkerId { get; set; }

    bool SendMarkerClick();

    bool SendInfoWindowClick()

;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how i can pass this from MainPage.xaml.cs to my MainPageViewModel.cs

```
 private void Pin_MarkerClicked(object sender, PinClickedEventArgs e)


{   
     var senderpin = (Pin)sender;           
 
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `MarkerClicked` is an event, not a Command, and cannot be bound.  If you want to bind to a command, use `EventToCommandBehavior` to bind the `MarkerClicked` **event** to a **VM Command**

Comment: I have previously tried to use the EventToCommandBehavior but it says the map has no behaviours

Comment: Please post that code

Comment: Odd, I would expect that to work.  You might just have to call the VM command from the event handler

Comment: @Jason Could you give me a bit of guidance please. How do i call the VM command from the event handler. Thanks

Comment: your page should have a reference to the VM, so you would just call `myVMInstance.MyMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EventToCommandBehavior` to set the command for the `MarkerClicked` event.

First, setting the name for the ContantPage.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         ...
         x:Name="this">
```

Second, you can bind the command in the ViewModel.

```
<maps:Map.Behaviors>
     <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior                            
         EventName="MarkerClicked"
         Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=BindingContext.Pin_MarkerClicked}">
     </toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior>               
 </maps:Map.Behaviors>
```

Comment: This does not work.  I get System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Comment: Can you provide the code?